# Payload duplicate files Windows Phone 8.1 Telerik

Tags: c#, telerik

Strange error when using Telerik UI For Windows Phone 8.1 Version 2015.1.226.45. And before you ask i cleaned my project deleted obj and bins but still same issue occours.

> Error 4   Payload contains two or more files with the same destination
>   path 'Telerik.UI.Xaml.Chart\Themes\Generic.xbf'. Source files: 
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for Windows Universal Q1
>   2015\SDKs\Windows Phone 8.1\Telerik UI for Windows
>   Universal\Redist\CommonConfiguration\neutral\Telerik.UI.Xaml.Chart\Themes\Generic.xbf
>   C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WorldClock3New\WorldClock\WorldClock\bin\Release\Telerik.UI.Xaml.Chart\Themes\Generic.xbf   WorldClock

It happens even if i create a new project and just add the reference I am using Visual Studio 2013